# About inversion in a title

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

Usually we would say 'the making of XXX' to describe the production process of something. Like, the making of a car...etc.

But I just heard somebody said 'XXX making of' as an activity title. The title is like "Car making of". May I ask if this inversion sounds natural, as an activity title?

Comment: Hello, Jane. Without more reasonable and verifiable context, this question may well be closed. This sounds like militarese listing format (Uniforms, dress, two.) My friend used to like parodying this: "Sacks, ruck: pairs, a half! Sir!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not. However, with punctuation and an article you can make it better:

> X: The Making Of

The only way I can think of that the construction in your question sounds at all natural would be in an index or glossary. The general subject (X) comes first, and the specific entry then adds more specificity. But that's very unlikely to be something someone would say out loud, unless deliberately imitating the index/glossary entry style.